# Jquery Variable Not Passing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue where I cannot seem to pass the variable "notes" into the placeholder of a form. More Info Below Code:

```
   request.done(function(data) {

                   window.notes = data;
                   //document.write(notes);

                });
                request.fail(function() {
                   // document.write("fail");
                                     });

                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('form').find("textarea").each(function(ev)
                    {
                        if(!$(this).val()) {


                           // document.write(notes); Says undefined?
                            $(this).attr("placeholder",window.notes);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

The placeholder code works...if I use

```
  $(this).attr("placeholder","test");
```

It works without problem as it should, but it will not if I try to use the var notes.

The setting of var notes works as well. If I uncomment the `document.write("notes")` I get the value I expect.

I have tried:

I originally started with `Var notes = data;` but moved to `window.notes` based on a suggestion by another question to make it global. Did not work. I also tried "forcing" the variable to be global by setting outside the function scope empty, but that didn't work either.. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Comment: its a variable scope issue.

Comment: I assumed that, but I don't seem to be able to resolve that. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't use it because the variable is not as global so you have to pass it into function and get it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I don't have much credit to comment . I just wanted to say that the document.ready function works on load at the starting of the page load while request.done or request.fail works after it so initially on load the window.notes is undefined.
And when you use the code document.write(notes) it gets defined and hence no error.

Comment: That was it. Rookie mistake on my part. Thanks!